# Is there a way to display the table orgin for rows in a union

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

When I union n amount of tables is there a way to add a column to result set that says what table that row came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - add a hard coded text column to each statement.

```
select 'This came from table A' as SourceTable, Id, Name
  from TableA
--
union
--
select 'This came from table B' as SourceTable, Id, Name
  from TableB
```

Comment: No problem - I'd appreciate it if you could mark this as the answer.

Comment: Had to wait the time limit